How to conditionally fill between two line charts with different colours using Plotly in Streamlit?
I'm trying to fill with colour the space between two line charts (between col1 and col2) as follows:

Desired output:

when col1 is above col2, fill with color green.
if col1 is under col2, fill with color red.

I have tried this:
def DisplayPlot(df):
   
    month = df['month'].tolist()
    col1 = df['col1'].tolist()
    col2 = df['col2'].tolist()
    col3 = df['col3'].tolist()

   
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=month, y=col1, name='col1', line=dict(color='blue', width=4)))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=month, y=col2, name = 'col2',line= dict(color='red', width=2)))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=month, y=col3, name='col3',mode='lines',line = dict(color='#CDCDCD', width=2, dash='dot')))

    # Edit the layout
    fig.update_layout(
            title=dict(
                text='Title'
            ),
            xaxis=dict(
                title=dict(
                    text='Month'
                )
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title=dict(
                    text='Taux'
                )
            ),
    )
    st.plotly_chart(fig)

But I have no idea how to add the colour based on the condition above.
Here's the dataset:



MONTH
COL1
COL2
COL3




Jan
0.1555
0.1256
0.1863


Feb
0.1097
0.119
0.1863


Apr
0.1459
0.175
0.1863


Mar
0.2804
0.2634
0.1863


May
0.267
0.1855
0.1863




Do the values in the shared dataset have commas, or are these decimal values? Please correct it if it's the latter.

yes decimal values, it gives this error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

it gives this error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

You'll have to understand that the line plot contains segments and you'll have to handle those segments separately to get the desired result.
By segments I mean the regions between the lines of col1 and col2. The segments are separated from each other by the intersections of the lines.
The following conditions are needed to be handled for each segment:

col1 is above col2 throughout the segment
col2 is above col1 throughout the segment
Handling the intersections during which the above conditions get reversed (We need to find these intersections using linear interpolation)
Handling parallel lines to avoid division by zero errors (refer to the code below for more clarity)

Here's the DisplayPlot function to handle the above conditions:
def DisplayPlot(df):
    if df["month"].dtype == "object":
        df["month"] = (
            pd.Categorical(
                df["month"],
                categories=["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
                ordered=True,
            ).codes
            + 1
        )

    month = df["month"]
    col1 = df["col1"]
    col2 = df["col2"]
    col3 = df["col3"]

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=month, y=col1, name="col1", line=dict(color="blue", width=4))
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=month, y=col2, name="col2", line=dict(color="red", width=2))
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=month,
            y=col3,
            name="col3",
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(color="#CDCDCD", width=2, dash="dot"),
        )
    )

    # Iterate through segments and fill regions conditionally
    for i in range(1, len(month)):
        x1, x2 = month[i - 1], month[i]
        y1_col1, y2_col1 = col1[i - 1], col1[i]
        y1_col2, y2_col2 = col2[i - 1], col2[i]

        # Check if col1 is above col2 throughout the segment
        if y1_col1 > y1_col2 and y2_col1 > y2_col2:
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=[x1, x2, x2, x1],
                    y=[y1_col1, y2_col1, y2_col2, y1_col2],
                    fill="toself",
                    fillcolor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",  # Green fill
                    mode="none",
                    showlegend=False,
                )
            )
        # Check if col2 is above col1 throughout the segment
        elif y1_col1 < y1_col2 and y2_col1 < y2_col2:
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=[x1, x2, x2, x1],
                    y=[y1_col2, y2_col2, y2_col1, y1_col1],
                    fill="toself",
                    fillcolor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",  # Red fill
                    mode="none",
                    showlegend=False,
                )
            )
        else:  # Handle crossing lines within the segment
            # Avoid division by zero by checking if the difference is non-zero
            denominator = (y2_col1 - y1_col1) - (y2_col2 - y1_col2)
            if denominator != 0:
                # Find the intersection point using linear interpolation
                intersect_x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((y1_col2 - y1_col1) / denominator)
                intersect_y = y1_col1 + (intersect_x - x1) * (
                    (y2_col1 - y1_col1) / (x2 - x1)
                )

                # Fill green where col1 is above
                if y1_col1 > y1_col2:
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[x1, intersect_x, intersect_x, x1],
                            y=[y1_col1, intersect_y, intersect_y, y1_col2],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )

                    # Fill red where col2 is above
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[intersect_x, x2, x2, intersect_x],
                            y=[intersect_y, y2_col1, y2_col2, intersect_y],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )
                else:
                    # Fill red where col2 is above
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[x1, intersect_x, intersect_x, x1],
                            y=[y1_col2, intersect_y, intersect_y, y1_col1],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )

                    # Fill green where col1 is above
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[intersect_x, x2, x2, intersect_x],
                            y=[intersect_y, y2_col2, y2_col1, intersect_y],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )
            else:
                # If lines are parallel, fill based on initial conditions
                if y1_col1 > y1_col2:
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[x1, x2, x2, x1],
                            y=[y1_col1, y2_col1, y2_col2, y1_col2],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )
                else:
                    fig.add_trace(
                        go.Scatter(
                            x=[x1, x2, x2, x1],
                            y=[y1_col2, y2_col2, y2_col1, y1_col1],
                            fill="toself",
                            fillcolor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                            mode="none",
                            showlegend=False,
                        )
                    )

    month_mapping = {1: "Jan", 2: "Feb", 3: "Mar", 4: "Apr", 5: "May", 6: "Jun"}

    fig.update_layout(
        title=dict(text="Comparison of col1 and col2"),
        xaxis=dict(
            title=dict(text="Month"),
            tickvals=list(month_mapping.keys()),
            ticktext=list(month_mapping.values()),
        ),
        yaxis=dict(title=dict(text="Values")),
        showlegend=True,
    )

    st.plotly_chart(fig)

You can find a full working example here with the corresponding Streamlit application deployed here.
Update1: As you have shared the months are strings and not numbers - you can just add this at the start of the function and it should work (updated the code above as well):
def DisplayPlot(df):
    if df["month"].dtype == "object":
        df["month"] = (
            pd.Categorical(
                df["month"],
                categories=["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
                ordered=True,
            ).codes
            + 1
        )
.
.
.

Also, you can have more months in the categories as per your requirement. I have kept it to the minimum for brevity.
Update2: We can use a mapping dictionary to replace the numbers with month names during the final layout update as follows (updated the original code as well):
.
.
.
    month_mapping = {1: "Jan", 2: "Feb", 3: "Mar", 4: "Apr", 5: "May", 6: "Jun"}

    fig.update_layout(
        title=dict(text="Comparison of col1 and col2"),
        xaxis=dict(
            title=dict(text="Month"),
            tickvals=list(month_mapping.keys()),
            ticktext=list(month_mapping.values()),
        ),
        yaxis=dict(title=dict(text="Values")),
        showlegend=True,
    )
    
    st.plotly_chart(fig)
.
.
.


thanks for your time ser, typing this code.
when I apply my dataset it breaks g in this line : intersect_x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((y1_col2 - y1_col1) / denominator) I will update the pose with mly dataset please

The error is coming because I assumed the values of months would be numbers - but these are strings - will fix it and update the answer soon. Thanks for sharing the sample dataset.

@innov-aphp Could you please try the updated code? You can see the updated code in the GitHub link and changes in the deployed app under the "Actual Dataset" dropdown.

thanks Yes t works ..but is there a way to display the month as string in the graph instead of numbers please ?

@innov-aphp I'll have to see what I can do - basically, the problem with that is we need the numerical values for interpolation and plotting - but if I somehow replace the plotting part with the names - it won't work because the intersections will not have any "month" associated to them (see the graph - you'll know what I mean - the intercepts mostly lie between two months so we'll have to handle this part somehow).
I'll update in case I figure something out.

thank you so much for your help..i will try from side too.

i have tried to do a function to transform the month i got this : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

@innov-aphp Updated the answer with the fix for month names as well. Check the deployed app to visualize the changes.

thank you so much for your time and effort. it works as expected.
thanks a lot again :)
